# What do you call one who believes in a higher power but doesn't call it "God"?

Tags: terminology, religion, philosophy

What do you call a person who believes in a higher power but doesn't call that higher power "God"?    Someone who respects every religion as a subject of study, or a valid belief system, but does not believe entirely any religion's faith himself?

Comment: All capitals is hard to read.

Comment: @k1eran So make it easier to read.

Comment: @AndrewLeach my comment was directed at OP so he'd know for the next time !

Comment: Well you could call them a monotheist and then maybe add as a caveat that they aren't attached to any particular organised faith. Nonetheless, this is very subjective.

Comment: Those two sentences sound like two different questions. The first _sounds_ like a non-Abrahamic monotheist (Muslims believe in the god of the Christian Old Testament (also Jews) but usually call them Allah rather than God; I don't know if they are included in you first sentence). Your second sentence...seems to have two distinct parts; the first is 'tolerant' or 'anthropologist' or 'religiologist' (not a word; but 'theologist' is already taken by believers), the second is 'areligious' or 'agnostic'. Some have joked that 'Jesuit' fits the whole second sentence.

Comment: Pantheist perhaps. Probably you need a little more to go on.

Comment: @Mitch Allah comes from the Arabic Al-Ilah meaning The God. It's a question of if you refer to the word as the semiotics of the word or the phonetic physical emanation of the word itself. Middle Eastern Christians still call God by Allah.

Comment: @AER The OP said "__call__ that higher power 'God'" so one might expect they want that particular label. It's a theological/philosophical discussion to decide if all those referents are the same deity.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, you can call or invoke something my name or by the semiotic. The word god itself comes from Proto-Germanic to invoke. Which can either be the semiotic notion or the phonetic. I think you're strictly adhering to call to mean enunciate words with the mouth. I'll offer a counterexample: God in the Platonic sense can also be referred to as Truth, or Beauty, or Goodness, or any other transcendental.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple categories to this. I'll arrange them in order of strictness:

1. **Atheist:** Believes absolutely in no higher power (however this definition has shifted somewhat to mean that they are agnostic as below, but in practical terms a higher power is irrelevant);
2. **Agnostic:** Not sure in the existence of a higher power either way;
3. **Deist:** Believes in a god but not one which has been revealed and is only observable in nature generally not from supernatural observances or revelation;
4. **Theist:** Believes in a higher power that has a person and is revealed in nature; and
5. **Religious:** Someone with a more firm set of beliefs and frameworks around said higher power.

An important aspect of the semantics would be to ask does God to you refer to a Christian god as in this situation. Capitalised God means the God, as in the Arabic Al-Ilah, meaning the God. Which is a different concept to the polytheistic Greek gods. Not just a higher power but the source of unity of all things. Whereas in traditional Jewish culture there was YHWH (pronunciation uncertain) which was the personal name for what they saw as the one God known as El (even though El himself was a god of the Canaanites).

To shift away from the Abrahamic traditions, in my limited knowledge Hinduism has a concept of the Atma or the universal consciousness which is in all things. And the Hindu structure has many facets of God and gods that can be interpreted in a strict Western sense as monotheist, panentheist, pantheist, or polytheistic. But is more about trying to find the whole in the divided.

Comment: Nope. The "shift" i atheism is toward the stance that the belief in God has not been justified by the claimants. Deists believe in a god that does not intervene in human affairs, thus they're god is not one with whom human beings can have a personal relationship.

Comment: @deadrat Good point about Deism, I've made that definition more strict. Secondly, then what differentiates an atheist and an agnostic then? Unless it is defined merely as opposition to those who claim a belief in a god/God. Similar in belief but different in motivation.

Comment: There is no agreement on terms. Atheism is about belief, and *atheist* is used to describe people who believe that the theistic claim is false (sometimes called *strong atheism*) and people who do not believe that the theistic claim is true (sometimes called *weak atheism*). Strong atheists make a counterclaim to theism; weak atheists, don't -- they just don't accept the theistic claim. Agnosticism is about knowledge, and it has two usages also -- to describe people who believe that gods are inherently unknowable and also to describe weak atheists. I hope that helps, but I doubt it.

Comment: @deadrat So my definition above still holds then? Thanks for spelling it out though. There's a lot of subtlety in the semantics. For example do agnostics know we can not know anything about God or do they not know if we can know anything about God.

Comment: From my reading, I believe that the particular type of agnostic denies that we can know anything about God.

Answer (score 3):

> What do you call a person who believes in a higher power but doesn't
>   call that higher power "God"?

The generic [theist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theism) works fine here:

> belief in the existence of a god or gods; specifically :  belief in
>   the existence of one God viewed as the creative source of the human
>   race and the world who transcends yet is immanent in the world

Theism is belief in some form of god/gods, but it does not require (or imply) respect for all or any other religions. The second use requested is therefore different:

> Someone who respects every religion as a subject of study, or a valid
>   belief system, but does not believe entirely any religion's faith
>   himself?

The closest set of words is perhaps that you "believe in religious tolerance". The set of beliefs also nears [Universalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universalism), but "Universalist" by itself may make it unclear as to exactly what you mean (as there are also Unitarians, Christian Universalists, etc). You might also just say you are "spiritual but not religious" (a popular non-committal sort of statement).

Comment: Nope. *Theism* works not at all here, since by your own source defines the word as belief in the existence of *a god....*

Answer (score 1):

It's called a *pantheist.*

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantheism):

> > 1 :  a doctrine that equates God with the forces and laws of the universe
> >
> > 2 :  the worship of all gods of different creeds, cults, or peoples indifferently; also :  toleration of worship of all gods (as at certain periods of the Roman empire)

A description from Wikipedia:

> > Pantheism is the belief that all of reality is identical with divinity, or that everything composes an all-encompassing, immanent god. Pantheists thus do not believe in a distinct personal or anthropomorphic god.

Comment: Nope. Any word that has a definition including the term *God* (as yours does) won't do the trick. By the way, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: OP stated the word "God" so pedantry may ask that no definition include it, but pantheism typically uses "God" in a very abstract, metaphorical sense. If the definition says "equates with" then the fact that the definition happens to contain that word is happenstance or it's used purely as a tool to convey its meaning in a way that is easily understood. In an abstract sense, it just means higher power, and that is represented by the universe and forces of nature. It's the same with "God doesn't play dice" (Albert Einstein). It's not literal. Pantheism is the correct answer.

Comment: The problem with *pantheism* is that it either means "recognition that all is God" (as you state) or "recognition of all gods".

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think your two examples necessarily describe equivalent people, I like the term **skeptic** based on the "practice" of **skepticism**

: *2a. The doctrine that true knowledge or knowledge in a particular area is uncertain; 2b. The method of suspended judgment, systematic doubt, or criticism characteristic of skeptics; 3. Doubt concerning basic religious principles such as immortality, providence, and revelation.* [Webster's]

"Higher power" is a term frequently used in addiction recovery circles.

Comment: Doesn't imply belief in a higher power though, more a style of epistemology

Comment: Nope. Skepticism is too broad, as it is applied to claims other than god claims, and it would likely reject a "higher power" as unprovien.